# How to use two dataframes to get to final dataframe based on keywords?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two dataframes -

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ColE': ['Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry-standard dummy text ever since the d4, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.','Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from d15 BC, making it over d10 years old.'],
                    'ColF': ['F1', 'F1'],
                    'ColG': ['G1', 'G1'],
                    'ColH': ['H1', 'H2'],
                    'ColJ': ['J1', 'J2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'ColB': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'ColC': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'ColD': ['d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6', 'd7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12', 'd13,d14,d15,d16,d17,d18']})
```

how to get dataframe df01 from above two dataframes such that if any of the keywords from df2['ColD'] is present in df1['ColE'] it will subsequently return values from ColA, ColB, ColC, and ColD separated with comma and put the same in ColA0, ColB0, ColC0, ColD1 in df1 like -

```
df01 = pd.DataFrame({'ColE': ['Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry-standard dummy text ever since the d4, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.','Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from d15 BC, making it over d10 years old.'],
                    'ColF': ['F1', 'F1'],
                    'ColG': ['G1', 'G1'],
                    'ColH': ['H1', 'H2'],
                    'ColJ': ['J1', 'J2'],
                    'ColD1': ['d4', 'd10,d15'],
                    'ColA0': ['A1', 'A2,A3'],
                    'ColB0': ['B1', 'B2,B3'],
                    'ColC0': ['C1', 'C2,C3'],
                   })
```

The code that worked on -

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ColE': ['Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the d4, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.',
                             'Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from d15 BC, making it over d10 years old.'],
                    'ColF': ['F1', 'F1'],
                    'ColG': ['G1', 'G1'],
                    'ColH': ['H1', 'H2'],
                    'ColJ': ['J1', 'J2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'ColB': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'ColC': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'ColD': ['d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6', 'd7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12', 'd13,d14,d15,d16,d17,d18']})

df2['ColD'] = df2['ColD'].str.split(',')

df1['ColD1'] = df1['ColE'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([keyword.strip() for keyword in df2['ColD'].sum() if keyword in x]))
df1['ColA0'] = df1['ColD1'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(df2.loc[df2['ColD'].apply(lambda y: any(keyword in y for keyword in x.split(','))), 'ColA']))
df1['ColB0'] = df1['ColD1'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(df2.loc[df2['ColD'].apply(lambda y: any(keyword in y for keyword in x.split(','))), 'ColB']))
df1['ColC0'] = df1['ColD1'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(df2.loc[df2['ColD'].apply(lambda y: any(keyword in y for keyword in x.split(','))), 'ColC']))

df01 = df1
```

This gives the following output -

| ColE | ColF | ColG | ColH | ColJ | ColD1 | ColA0 | ColB0 | ColC0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printi.. | F1 | G1 | H1 | J1 | d4 | A1 | B1 | C1 |
| Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not.. | F1 | G1 | H2 | J2 | d1,d10,d15 | A1,A2,A3 | B1,B2,B3 | C1,C2,C3 |

The expected output is -

| ColE | ColF | ColG | ColH | ColJ | ColD1 | ColA0 | ColB0 | ColC0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printi.. | F1 | G1 | H1 | J1 | d4 | A1 | B1 | C1 |
| Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not.. | F1 | G1 | H2 | J2 | d10,d15 | A2,A3 | B2,B3 | C2,C3 |

How to make it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `keyword in x` is true for `d1` since `d1` is part of `d10` and `d15`. You need to use a regex search instead to ensure you only match the complete word. Note for efficiency you should compute the `ColD` sum only once, and keep `ColD1` as a list until you are finished with it:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ColE': ['Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry-standard dummy text ever since the d4, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.','Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from d15 BC, making it over d10 years old.'],
                    'ColF': ['F1', 'F1'],
                    'ColG': ['G1', 'G1'],
                    'ColH': ['H1', 'H2'],
                    'ColJ': ['J1', 'J2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'ColB': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'ColC': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'ColD': ['d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6', 'd7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12', 'd13,d14,d15,d16,d17,d18']})

all_keywords = df2['ColD'].str.split(',').sum()

df1['ColD1'] = df1['ColE'].apply(lambda x: [keyword.strip() for keyword in all_keywords if re.search(fr'\b{keyword}\b', x)])
df1['ColA0'] = df1['ColD1'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(df2.loc[df2['ColD'].apply(lambda y: any(keyword in y for keyword in x)), 'ColA']))
df1['ColB0'] = df1['ColD1'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(df2.loc[df2['ColD'].apply(lambda y: any(keyword in y for keyword in x)), 'ColB']))
df1['ColC0'] = df1['ColD1'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(df2.loc[df2['ColD'].apply(lambda y: any(keyword in y for keyword in x)), 'ColC']))
df1['ColD1'] = df1['ColD1'].apply(','.join)
```

Output:

```
                                                ColE ColF ColG ColH ColJ    ColD1  ColA0  ColB0  ColC0
0  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printi...   F1   G1   H1   J1       d4     A1     B1     C1
1  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not...   F1   G1   H2   J2  d10,d15  A2,A3  B2,B3  C2,C3
```

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing the confusion :)
this works just perfectly!